# Flex bind variable has no effect

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, mxml

No matter what I do, I cannot have any effect on Flex MXML elements during initialization.
I want to display a different logo depending on whether a flashVar is true or not.

For some reason the flashvar has no effect on how the elements appear.

Am I missing anything ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
     xmlns:components="ru.kutu.grindplayer.views.components.*"
     mouseEnabled="false"
     implements="ru.kutu.grind.views.api.IMainView"
     preinitialize="preinitialize(event)"
     >

<s:states>
    <s:State name="initializing" />
    <s:State name="ready" />
    <s:State name="error" />
</s:states>

<s:BorderContainer 
    id="logoContainer"
    left="0" right="0"
    top="0" bottom="0"
    mouseEnabled="false"
    includeIn="initializing"
    backgroundColor="0x070707"
    borderVisible = "false"
>
    <s:Image  
        id="logoPaid"
        verticalCenter="0"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        source="@Embed('/../assets/skin/dark.png')"
        visible="{is_paid}"
    />
    <s:Image  
        id="logoFree"
        verticalCenter="0"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        source="@Embed('/../assets/skin/dark_free.png')"
        visible="{!is_paid}"
    />
</s:BorderContainer> 

<components:PlayerView
    id="playerView"
    left="0" right="0"
    top="0" bottom="0"
    visible="false"
    visible.ready="true"
    />

<s:Label
    id="errorDisplay"
    width="80%"
    mouseEnabled="false"
    verticalCenter="0"
    horizontalCenter="0"
    includeIn="error"
    itemCreationPolicy="immediate"
    />


<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition
        fromState="*" toState="*"
        autoReverse="true"
        interruptionBehavior="stop"
        >
        <s:Fade 
            target="{this}"
            duration="300"
          />
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        private var is_paid:Boolean; 

        public function set errorText(value:String):void {
            errorDisplay.text = value;
        }

        public function initializing(is_paid:Boolean):void {
            currentState = "initializing";
        }

        public function ready():void {
            currentState = "ready";
        }

        public function error():void {
            currentState = "error";
        }

        private function preinitialize(event:FlexEvent):void {
            is_paid = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.is_paid;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: What do you see if you change `preinitialize()` to simply set `is_paid = true;` ?

Comment: is_paid = true or is_paid = false there does seem to take effect it seems.. good catch ! What else can break here?
I double checked and the object gets the correct flashvar ( is_paid=true/is_paid=false )

Comment: Did you try to set width and height to logoContainer? Maybe "initializing" is   fast so you can't see it? Try tracing times between states.

Comment: I am referring to includeIn="initializing"

Comment: The initializing state lasts for around 4 seconds .. it needs to load OSMF and several other big libraries.. and it seems it does apply the right style and display it when I hard-set the value

Comment: To clarify, setting is_paid = true *does* or *doesn't* take effect?  Either way, you could try compiling with `keep-generated-actionscript=true` and look at the class generated out of this MXML file.

Comment: It does take effect.

Comment: @Daniel, what is your problem, you can't see any image or Fade Effect doesn't play?

Comment: The problem is -> when I put "true" in the is_paid flashvar the logoPaid image shows , but when I put "false" in it, it still shows logoPaid even though I expect logoFree to be shown instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you parse String into Boolean. Cause params names and values are String, try this instead:

```
is_paid = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.is_paid == 'true';
```

Comment: Holy heck yes ! that was it ! I guess too much PHP and Javascript made me forget normal languages don't think 'false' is false... Thanks !